# Presigned URL using IAM User - Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, pre-signed-url

I have an S3 bucket that I would like to allow conditional file access to via a presigned URL. I'm using Boto3 to generate the URL, and I've created an IAM role with an inline policy giving it access to the bucket. I've also updated the bucket policy to allow this user Get, Put, and Delete permissions. Still, when I try a get to the generated presigned URL, I am receiving an access denied error. Am I blatantly missing an AWS setting here? All of the documentation I've read points to my setup being sufficient.

My IAM User Inline Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Example permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "IAM-USER-ARN"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "IAM-USER-ARN"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Boto3 Code to Generate URL (using profile with access & secret key for IAM role in ~/.aws/credentials):

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='IAM-PROFILE')
            s3_client = session.client(
                's3', 
                'us-east-2',
                config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
            )
            presigned_response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
                'get_object', 
                Params = {'Bucket': 'BUCKET-NAME', 'Key': 'FILE-NAME.png'}, 
                ExpiresIn = 3600
            )
```

Comment: is your credentials located `~/.aws/` correctly? Notify dot here.

Comment: @Lamanus yes it is. Thanks, I edited my question, I typed that part incorrectly. I know the credential file is correct because I have other profiles with their keys located inside of it that are working correctly.

Comment: I want to point out the the bucket policy does not matter. The IAM policy alone should grant access to the bucket without needing to declare it in the bucket policy. For the problem, I would say make sure that the bucket name and file name are correct and that they both exist (and that the file is not in a folder).